# Can't connect to wifi after installing Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: networking, drivers

I have bought a new laptop recently, Lenovo Legion Y540 and installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 in dual-boot with windows 10 home. After installation, I was unable to connect to wifi, I read a lot of articles and different answers, but none of them worked for me. I don't have the possibility to connect by an Ethernet cable and also the terminal doesn't have some of the essential commands, so the only possibility is to figure out what is wrong with Wifi.
**Update:** In some articles was recommended to download the drivers using terminal manually, but since I can't connect to internet, that's imposible and also to use some commands which the terminal didn't recognize, as it was suggesting to install them, for example "make". The wifi button stays always grey and if I press "Turn on", nothing happens, it indicates that it is off.

Wifi adapter: Intel Wireless-AC 9560.

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9560 
[Jefferson Peak] [8086:a370] (rev 10)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0034]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: yes
2: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

**Uptate**
@David What do I do if  there isn't any configure file?

```
  radu@Radu-Legion-Y540-15IRH:~/Desktop$ tar xvfz iwl.tgz
  iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0/
  iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode
  iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0/LICENSE.iwlwifi-9000.ucode
  iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.618819.0/README.iwlwifi-9000.ucode
  radu@Radu-Legion-Y540-15IRH:~/Desktop$ cd iwl1
  radu@Radu-Legion-Y540-15IRH:~/Desktop/iwl1$ ls
  iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-34.ucode  README.iwlwifi-9000.ucode
  LICENSE.iwlwifi-9000.ucode
  radu@Radu-Legion-Y540-15IRH:~/Desktop/iwl1$ ./configure
  bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` and also: `rfkill list all` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: What exactly does "the terminal doesn't have some of the essential commands" mean?

Comment: When you **[edit]** this to provide the information requested by chili555 and to answer user535733's question (both in comments above), I recommend that you also expand on *"I read a lot of articles and different answers, but none of them worked for me."* Without saying specifically *what* you have attempted, you're likely to get answers recommending the same techniques that you've already tried unsuccessfully. Furthermore, in addition to describing everything you've done already, please also describe *what happened* when you did it.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You say you don't have internet access, but you are posting here.. do you have a flash drive that you could use to transfer the drivers over from whatever you are using to access AU to your laptop?

Comment: @David As I said, I installed Ubuntu in dual-boot with windows 10 and yeah, I have a flash drive to transfer data, the actual problem is that I don't know what and how to install the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Your wireless adapter is blocked by `rfkill`

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf <<< "blacklist ideapad_laptop"
```

and reboot.